# Blindly calling a public method (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, public-method

OK, weird one. I have many usercontrols with a repeater, the layout of the repeater is the same in all controls, and they all have a `bindData()` method publically available.

I'm wondering, can I setup another usercontrol for paging without having to specify the parent control?

I'm able to do the following:

```
((controls.specificuserControlClass)Parent).bindData();
```

Which is all fine - however I'd need to specify the `specificuserControlClass` into the pager and then would need it "per repeater" if you see what I mean?

So can I call `Parent.bindData()` blindly from the child control? I "know" that method exists (or would build checks to make sure), however Visual Studio isn't happy as it doesn't know of the method.

Comment: Does the bindData() method come from an interface?  If not, can it?

Comment: @zimdanen Looking at the answer below, I'm sure it can, I'm just trying it out now!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not make your controls all implement a specific interface?

```
 public interface IBindData
 {
      void bindData();
 }
```

Then, you would simply do:

```
((IBindData)Parent).bindData()
```

And it should invoke each control's method as appropriate.

Comment: Either that, or use Reflection.

Comment: Personally, I would rather override `OnItemCreated` and take the code out of the view, but that's also going to be more work =D

Comment: Curse your speed, @Tejs, that was going to be my answer! :) +1

Comment: Speed indeed! THanks guys - my migration (of skills) from VB.NET to C# is going slowly, nice to learn something new :)

Comment: This is nothing that you can't do in VB, the syntax is slightly different but the concepts are identical.